# Getting Invalid string length error in NodeJS for a big payload

Tags: node.js, string, out-of-memory, overflow

My service is parsing a request and creating a PDF from the contents. For a big payload, the request fails with this error -

```
RangeError: Invalid string length
```

It works fine on a smaller payload.
For every entry in the request, I'm processing and concatenating in a string and the string overflows. What other way can I use in this scenario, I've thought about using files to add the content but then I'm also using ejs templating engine and will have to load the content back in memory.

Comment: You can use transform stream to make it work. check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93/).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response.
I'll try the stream thing, but if I need to pass the whole string to a templating function, then ultimately I'll have to put in a variable, or is there something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you could try, one is to increase memory by setting NODE_OPTIONS environment variable to some larger value (default is 512MB):

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=<size_in_mb>
```

Because this error can be thrown if your runtime is out of memory. Still, max value of this depends on version of Node.js you're using (more correctly which V8 version is used underneath)

If you don't want to use streams, you could try with buffer, which has a bit larger allocation, which you can check by running this command in your node runtime (result is in G):

```
(require('buffer').constants.MAX_LENGTH + 1) / 2**30
```

But remember to set corresponding max size in your NODE_OPTIONS

Comment: Thank you for responding. I was getting heap issue too, so I've already set the max space size to 4 GB. But now I'm getting the invalid string length error, which I assume is thrown as string's capacity has been maxed out.
Now, I'm not sure how do I process the entire string without causing an overflow.